# ZF3 - Callback validator attaches error message to wrong input

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have a form where a radio button field should be required based on an option from a select field. Also there's a text field that also should be required if the radio button option "yes" is selected.
I'm using a callback validator for both fields to check this dependency but the problem is that the error message is being attached to the wrong field. For example if I select an option from the select and leave the radio buttons unchecked, the validator works, but the error message is shown in the select input and not in the radio button.

I wrote two validators for this fields based on an answer by "rkeet" on this post:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/issues/146

```
$inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'regimenPreferencia',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => NotEmpty::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'message' => [
                            NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Ingrese el régimen de preferencia para este artículo'
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => Callback::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'callback' => function($value, $context) {

                            var_dump($value, $context);
                            if($value === 'agricultura_familiar' && empty($context['esCompraCentralizada'])) {
                                $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['esCompraCentralizada']->getValidatorChain();
                                $validatorChain->attach(new NotEmpty(['type' => NotEmpty::NULL]));
                                $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['esCompraCentralizada']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                                return false;
                            }

                            return true;
                        },
                        'messages' => [
                            Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Indique si esta compra es centralizada'
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'allow_empty' => false,
            'continue_if_empty' => false,
        ]);

        $inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'esCompraCentralizada',
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => Callback::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'callback' => function($value, $context) {

                            if(strlen($value) > 0 && empty($context['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado'])) {
                                $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->getValidatorChain();
                                $validatorChain->attach(new NotEmpty(['type' => NotEmpty::NULL]));
                                $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                                return false;
                            }

                            return true;
                        },
                        'messages' => [
                            'callbackValue' => 'Ingrese el porcentaje de adjudicación de reserva de mercado'
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],

            'continue_if_empty' => true
        ]);

        $inputFilter->add([
            'name' => 'porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado',
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => ToInt::class]
            ],
            'validators' => [

            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Nice to be referenced, first time I think. Looking at `esCompraCentralizada`, aren't you updating the incorrect ValidatorChain? `esCompra*` should be required if `porcAdju*` is set. As such, you should `$this->getInputFilter()->getInputs('esCompra*')->getValidatorChain()` and continue as you have. Same with your other Input callback. In the example on Github which you referenced, the NotEmpty's are attached _to the other_ input. So, 2 options:

Comment: 1 - with most of your current code, do as in previous comment and updated _the current_ Input's validator chain. 2 - Do as in the Github example and update _the other_ Input based on "this one's" value.

Comment: (In referenced example, pseudo code: if _latitude_ is set, make longitude && if _longitude_ is set, make latitude required)

Comment: Hi rkeet, thank you very much for your answer. Actually the field constraints should be like this: `esCompraCentralizada` should be required if `regimenPreferencia` is set and the value is `agricultura_familiar` and `porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado` should be required if `esCompraCentralizada` is set and the option 'yes' is selected. I'll test your approach and get back to you with the results. Thanks again.

Comment: How'd it go? Sticking with just `esCompra*` and `regi*` you can: 1 - callback on `esCompra*` checks, via context, if `regi*` is set, if yes then adds a `NotEmpty` validator on its own chain. 2 - callback on `regi*` checks if itself is set, if yes then adds a `NotEmpty` validator on `esCompra*` chain.  - The same would apply for the second case, with the added condition that it must be "set && true" instead of just set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made it work as I expected.
I added a Callback validator to esCompraCentralizada to check if it's empty and the rest of the validators where added to the porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado field.

This is how the validators ended up being:

```
$inputFilter->add([
        'name' => 'esCompraCentralizada',
        'required' => false,
        'allow_empty' => true,
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => Callback::class,
                'brake_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        if(!isset($context['esCompraCentralizada']) && $context['regimenPreferencia'] === 'agricultura_familiar') {
                            $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['esCompraCentralizada']->getValidatorChain();
                            $validatorChain->attach(new NotEmpty(['type' => NotEmpty::NULL]));
                            $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['esCompraCentralizada']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    'messages' => [
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Indique si esta compra es centralizada'
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $inputFilter->add([
        'name' => 'porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado',
        'required' => false,
        'allow_empty' => true,
        'filters' => [
            ['name' => ToInt::class]
        ],
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => Callback::class,
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        if($context['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado'] === '' && $context['esCompraCentralizada'] === '1' && $context['regimenPreferencia'] === 'agricultura_familiar') {
                            $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->getValidatorChain();
                            $validatorChain->attach(new NotEmpty(['type' => NotEmpty::NULL]));
                            $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    'messages' => [
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Ingrese el porcentaje de adjudicación de reserva de mercado'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => Callback::class,
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        if (!is_numeric($context['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']) && $context['regimenPreferencia'] === 'agricultura_familiar' && $context['esCompraCentralizada'] === '1') {
                            $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->getValidatorChain();
                            $validatorChain->attach(new LessThan());
                            $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    'message' => [
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'El porcentaje de adjudicación de reserva de mercado debe ser un valor numérico'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => Callback::class,
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        if ($value > 100 && $context['regimenPreferencia'] === 'agricultura_familiar' && $context['esCompraCentralizada'] === '1') {
                            $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->getValidatorChain();
                            $validatorChain->attach(new LessThan());
                            $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    'message' => [
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'El porcentaje de adjudicación de reserva de mercado debe ser menor o igual a 100'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => Callback::class,
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        if ($value < 30 && $context['regimenPreferencia'] === 'agricultura_familiar' && $context['esCompraCentralizada'] === '1') {
                            $validatorChain = $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->getValidatorChain();
                            $validatorChain->attach(new GreaterThan());
                            $this->getInputFilter()->getInputs()['porcAdjudicacionReservaMercado']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                            return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    'message' => [
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'El porcentaje de precio de materiales nacionales debe ser mayor o igual a 30'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

I added four validators to the second field to check:

- empty field
- field value not numeric
- field value less than 30 (functional requirement)
- field value greater than 100 (functional requirement)

All this applys if 'regimen_preferencia' is 'agricultura_familiar' and 'esCompraCentralizada' is true.

Thank you very much rkeet for all your help!